# R relative frequencies organized by Group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, frequency, summarize

I have the following data frame:

```
> LikelyRenew_ReasonB %>%
    +   mutate(cum_Sum = ave(freq,Name,FUN = cumsum))
          Name x freq cum_Sum
 1       costC 1   10      10
 2       costC 2   11      21
 3       costC 3   17      38
 4       costC 4  149     187
 5   productsC 1   31      31
 6   productsC 2   40      71
 7   productsC 3   30     101
 8   productsC 4   86     187
 9     communC 1   51      51
 10    communC 2   50     101
 11    communC 3   34     135
 12    communC 4   52     187
 13 reimburseC 1   42      42
 14 reimburseC 2   26      68
 15 reimburseC 3   25      93
 16 reimburseC 4   94     187
 17    policyC 1   31      31
 18    policyC 2   25      56
 19    policyC 3   28      84
 20    policyC 4  103     187
 21  discountC 1    2       2
 22  discountC 2    2       4
 23  discountC 3    3       7
 24  discountC 4  180     187
```

Here is what the variable looks like:

```
> dput(head(LikelyRenew_ReasonB))
structure(list(Name = c("costC", "costC", "costC", "costC", "productsC", 
"productsC"), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2), freq = c(10L, 11L, 17L, 
149L, 31L, 40L)), .Names = c("Name", "x", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to get for each group, the relative frequency for each frequency score and then the sum of the relative frequencies for the group. I put below a sample of what I am looking for - the 1st three rows are their freq/cum_Sum[x==4]. The last row should be a total of those 3 rows.

Is this possible?? I am totally stumped.

```
          Name x freq cum_Sum    IdealOutput   *how i calculated IdealOutput
 1       costC 1   10      10         5.35       (10/187)
 2       costC 2   11      21         5.88       (11/187)
 3       costC 3   17      38         9.09       (17/187) 
 4       costC 4  149     187         20.32      (sum of above 3 values)
```

Comment: How are your deciding to have `IdealOutput` as sum of all previous? Is it last row for that Name?

Comment: the x value 4 is coded for who are people who did not check that that  product was one of the top 3 for selling points for them. So this way I'd have relative frequencies for choosing a product as number 1,2, or 3, and the relative frequency that the product as a whole was selected as the top 3 (what the last r freq calculates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `dplyr::lag` on `cum_Sum` to calculate `IdealOutput` for last row of a group.

The last row of a group can be found using condition as `row_number() == n()`

```
library(dplyr)

LikelyRenew_ReasonB %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Name, x) %>%
  mutate(cum_Sum = cumsum(freq)) %>%
  mutate(IdealOutput = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 
                       lag(cum_Sum)/sum(freq), freq/sum(freq))) 

#   # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   # Groups: Name [2]
#   Name          x  freq cum_Sum IdealOutput
# <chr>     <dbl> <int>   <int>       <dbl>
# 1 costC      1.00    10      10      0.0535
# 2 costC      2.00    11      21      0.0588
# 3 costC      3.00    17      38      0.0909
# 4 costC      4.00   149     187      0.203 
# 5 productsC  1.00    31      31      0.437 
# 6 productsC  2.00    40      71      0.437
```

**Data:**

```
LikelyRenew_ReasonB  <- structure(list(Name = c("costC", "costC", "costC", "costC", "productsC", 
"productsC"), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2), freq = c(10L, 11L, 17L, 
149L, 31L, 40L)), .Names = c("Name", "x", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: it is giving the error: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!                                                              
         tweaked it a little to get it to work:                     
   LikelyRenew_ReasonB %>%
  group_by(Name)%>%
  arrange(Name,x)%>%
  mutate(cum_Sum = ave(freq,Name,FUN = cumsum))%>%
  mutate(relfreq = ifelse(x== 4,
                          dplyr::lag(cum_Sum)*100/cum_Sum,freq*100/cum_Sum[x==4]))

Comment: @ElaineSlaven Good to know it helped you. If you would have used my answer as is then it should have worked as well. You dont need to use `ave` with my solution.

Comment: I had it without ave but for some reason it wasn't restarting the count for the cum_Sum @ each group but with ave it worked

Comment: The output I have shared with answer is from the data shared by you. I think you could have restarted `RStudio`. Sometime that helps.